# `vlc` command line cannot play video with absolute path in Windows 7

Tags: vlc-media-player

The question is simple: I already add `vlc.exe` containing folder to system path. I can play a video using `vlc` command line when I change the directory to the video file containing folder and use the command `vlc [videofilename]`. But if I try to play a video with absolute path when the file is not in the current directory, `vlc` just start and no file playing. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I figure it out myself.
Just add `file:///` before the absolute file path, everything is fine.